# Mysql 5.5 server not working

Tags: 14.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

I had Ubuntu 14.04 installed on my system. I recently updated ubuntu and now my mysql does not start and workbench says that mysql server has been stopped. And when i try to start it gives me the following error

```
2014-08-12 23:02:04 - Checking server status...
2014-08-12 23:02:04 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2014-08-12 23:02:04 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) (2003)
2014-08-12 23:02:04 - Assuming server is not running
2014-08-12 23:02:04 - Server start done.
2014-08-12 23:02:04 - Checking server status...
2014-08-12 23:02:04 - Trying to connect to MySQL...
2014-08-12 23:02:04 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111) (2003)
2014-08-12 23:02:04 - Assuming server is not running
```

And also when i try to login using terminal (`mysql -u root -p <password>`) i get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I have also tried to reinstall Ubuntu but i am unable to do so. Gives me the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
mysql-server-5.5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

I have data which i have not taken backup of as i am unable to log into the server. I am a newbie please help me resolve this issue without losing my data.

Awaiting for your earliest response.

Below is the error message from cat /var/log/mysql/error.log

```
140813 21:22:50 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
140813 21:22:50 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
140813 21:22:50 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140813 21:22:50 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140813 21:22:50 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140813 21:22:50 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140813 21:22:50 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140813 21:22:50 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140813 21:22:50 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140813 21:22:50  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140813 21:22:51 InnoDB: 5.5.38 started; log sequence number 80726593570
140813 21:22:51 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '127.0.0.1'; port: 3306
140813 21:22:51 [Note]   - '127.0.0.1' resolves to '127.0.0.1';
140813 21:22:51 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '127.0.0.1'.
140813 21:22:51 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Incorrect file format 'user'
```

Comment: Is MySQL server started? What is the output of `sudo service mysql status`?

Comment: @Salem - This is the status i get "mysql stop/waiting"

Comment: So if you run `sudo service mysql start` it fails to start? Do you have any errors in `/var/log/mysql/error.log`?

Comment: @Salem - I am really new to ubuntu and I am not sure how to go about doing thing. Can u let me how do I check that ? Also i am unable to access /var/lib/mysql or home/mysql folder.

Comment: Just run `sudo service mysql start` and check if MySQL is running connecting with `mysql` command. IF not (you cant connect) check if you can find any info in that file

Comment: i get the following error if i try to start "start: Job failed to start". and also 1 of the solution said look for "*.sock" file where i was not able to find "mysqld.sock" on my system even logged in at root. But how do i read the error /var/log/mysql/error.log. Do i just open it with gedit? I have also tried to uninstall and reinstall only but that also failed.

Comment: You can use any text editor, it is a plain text file. Gedit, `nano`, `cat` etc. If that file has much text and no sensitive information, consider add the content  to paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: @Salem have added the error message from error.log above

Answer (score 1):

I would like to thank Salem who was very helpful in suggesting me various solutions for my problem.

I was unable to resolve my issue using those suggestions. And as I had very important data which I did not want to lose data.

Here is what I eventually did

1. Created a copy of `/var/lib/mysql`This helped me get back all the tables and the data inside without having to import the data again.

To get permission to access the files and folders in mysql ran the following:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/mysql
```

To get permission to access the files within folders in mysql ran the following:

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/mysql/*
```

2. Removed/Uninstalled mysql using the following commands:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
   sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-client-core-5.5
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   sudo apt-get autoclean
   sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
   ```

I had to remove the mysql-client-core-5.5 separately even if I used `autoremove` and `autoclean` as it used to give me an error when i was setting the root password as it said it was unable to create root user.

3. Install/Reinstall mysql server and client

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mysql-server
   sudo apt-get install mysql-client
   sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
   ```
4. Copied the files required (folders with the files relevant to my database names) back into the `/var/lib/mysql`folder.

Make sure you don't replace the base files from the new installation. As this again creates the same issue again where the server stops running again.